# Display multiple TextView on screen

Tags: android, layout, textview, xamarin, autolink

I am using `Xamarin` and I would like to display many `email`, `web addresses` and `phone numbers` for different users on a screen. Want to use the `AutoLink` feature of the `TextView`  to do this.

My question is this:  Which  is the best way to display the user details on a screen as some people have more than one phone number or email and some people have no email address?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use custom List Views and Adapters so that you build (render) dynamically the cells accordingly. You would be able to create TextFields for each data (email, phone numbers, etc) and control how many of each you show.